# How to show the previous and next image in the previous and next button in a carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, carousel

I am making a portfolio website, with a carousel to showcase my images. I have successfully coded the carousel to work. Now, I just have one obstacle: I want the 'Next' and 'Prev' button to show the next and previous image.

Right now, it seems like my code, do not know where the photos are. In this case, I cannot call for them. How can this be solved? Would I have to give every photo a unique class, or is there some way I can automate this?

[This photo illustrates my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbys9.jpg)

```
 <div class="cointainer  active">
    <ol class="content">


        <li class="slides"> <img src="image_01.jpg" height="500px">
            <div>
                <div class="date">
                    <p>
                    &copy; August Hugo <br>
                    Avelon <br>
                    26-09-19
                    </p>    
                </div>  
                <div class="desctiption">
                    <p> 

                    </p>

                </div>  
            </div>  
        </li>



        <li class="slides"> <img src="image_02.jpg" height="500px">
            <div>
                <div class="date">
                    <p> 
                    &copy; August Hugo <br>
                    Avelon <br>
                    26-09-19
                    </p>    
                </div>  
                <div class="desctiption">
                    <p>

                    </p>

                </div>  
            </div>  
        </li>



        <li class="slides"> <img src="image_03.jpg" height="500px" class="1">
            <div>
                <div class="date">
                    <p> &copy; August Hugo <br>
                    Avelon <br>
                    26-09-19 </p>   
                </div>  
                <div class="desctiption" align="left">
                    <p> 
                    </p>

                </div>  
            </div>  
        </li>



        <li class="slides"> <img src="image_04.jpg" height="500px">
            <div>
                <div class="date">
                    <p> &copy; August Hugo <br>
                    Avelon <br>
                    26-09-19 </p>   
                </div>  
                <div class="desctiption" align="left">
                    <p> 

                    </p>

                </div>  
            </div>
        </li>


    </ol>
</div>




<!--Next Button-->
    <button class="next" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">
        <img height="500px" width="80px">
    </button>

    <!--Prev Button-->
    <button class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">
        <img height="500px" width="80px">
    </button>


   var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
      }
      x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    }
```

Comment: Is it bootstrap carousel?

Comment: Hello, thank you for that notice. - No, it is not a bootstrap carousel.

Comment: To make things a bit clear could you add the code of your carousel? We don't really what you are interacting with.

Comment: Yes, I have added the code of the carousel now.

Comment: It looks like there is a list of images. I don't know what image is being shown initially or how is this code related to the image shown. You did mention `successfully coded the carousel to work` but I don't see that here.